# Adding data in React component via websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to add a data to a table of some operations in React via WebSockets. I even get the new data from WebSocket successfully. I stuck with the question how to add a new data to existing. When I recieve new data in websocket response, my const operationList becomes empty.

Have a look at my code:

```
const [operationsList, setOperationsList] = useState([{}] )

// Here I get the existing data from backend API and store to operationsList. It works
  async function fetchOperations(activeID) {
    if (activeID !== false) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/operations/?made_by=${activeID}`
      )
      setOperationsList(response.data)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOperationsLoading(true)
    fetchOperations(activeID)
      .then(() => {setIsOperationsLoading(false)})
      .catch((e) => {setOperationsError(e)})
  },[activeID])


// Here I subscribe to websockets to get new data for adding to operationsList
  useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/')
    ws.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      const response = JSON.parse(e.data)
      console.log(response) // Here I see new data. It's ok
      console.log(operationsList) // All of the sudden operationsList become empty
    })
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      action: "subscribe_to_operations_activity",
      request_id: new Date().getTime(),
    }))
    }
  }, [])
```

I thought that in my second **useEffect** I could just add response data from WebSocket like
**setOperationsList([response, operationsList])**. But **operationsList** is empty, so I've got just a new data in the table. How to fix it?

Comment: The second `useEffect` hook runs only once when the component mounts, you are logging the initial `operationsList` state value closed over in callback scope. What are you wanting to do with it there?

Comment: The first **useEffect** takes data from the database when the component is loaded. And I want to add to this uploaded rendered data a new data that I get from the second **useEffect**.

Comment: The second one **useEffect** establishes a websocket connection and when somebody puts new data in database I could see it in **console.log(response**. But the problem is that I've got no idea how to add this data to **operationsList**. The **operationsList** in the first **useEffect** becomes empty, though I can see the rendered data in component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `useEffect` hook runs only once when the component mounts, you are logging the initial `operationsList` state value closed over in callback scope. In other words, it's a stale enclosure over the `operationsList` state.

I'm guessing it's at this point you are wanting to append `response` to the `operationsList` state. You can use a functional state update to correctly access the previous state and append to it.

You may also want to unsubscribe to the `"message"` event in the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function. This is to prevent resource leaks and attempts to update state of unmounted components.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/');

  const handler = (e) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(e.data);

    setOperationsList(operationsList => [
      ...operationsList, // <-- shallow copy previous state
      response,          // <-- append new data
    ]);
  };

  ws.addEventListener('message', handler);

  ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      action: "subscribe_to_operations_activity",
      request_id: new Date().getTime(),
    }));
  };

  return () => {
    ws.removeEventListener('message', handler);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! But, please, coud you tell me why this code works and where can I read about this case?

Comment: @Ivan Does this [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) doc help at all? The React docs are generally pretty good, but in this case I think they assume a decent amount of base Javascript knowledge, here specifically with [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).